# Winsock API - send and receive data simultaneously in two threads

Tags: c++, winsock, send

I'm trying to build a client and a server in the same program. For example, user 1 sends a packet of data to user 2, user 2 after receiving the packet sends back a different packet to user 1. The problem is, after running the program neither user receives the packets.If I build the client in a separate program from the server it works

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

static const int num_threads = 2;

static char buffer[8096 + 1];
char a[256] = {};
char MOTD[256];

void call_from_thread(int tid) {
//  ---------- Server code: ---------- //
if( tid == 0 ){

WSAData wsaData;
WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0){MessageBoxA(NULL, "WinSock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);}

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1112);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

    SOCKET newConnection;
    newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
    if (newConnection == 0){
        std::cout << "Failed to accept the client's connection." << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Client Connected!" << std::endl;
    }

    while (true){
        std::cin >> a;
        send(newConnection, a, sizeof(a), NULL);
    }
}else if( tid == 1 ){


//  ---------- Client code: ---------- //
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0){MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);}

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); //Set Connection socket
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeofaddr) != 0) //If we are unable to connect...
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to Connect", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        //return 0; //Failed to Connect
    }

    std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;

    char MOTD[256];
    while (true){
        recv(Connection, MOTD, sizeof(MOTD), NULL); //Receive Message of the Day buffer into MOTD array
        std::cout << "MOTD:" << MOTD << std::endl;
    }
}



//  ---------- Thread selection: ---------- //
int main() {
std::thread t[num_threads];

for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
    t[i] = std::thread(call_from_thread, i);
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
     t[i].join();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The server is listening on port 1112, but the client is connecting to port 1111.  This means the client and server cannot possibly be connected to each other at all, whether they are in the same application or not.

I also see a number of other problems with your code, including:

- `WSAStartup()` should be called once at app startup, not per thread.
- Neither thread quits cleanly if any WinSock function fails.
- The client thread does not wait for the server thread to open its listening port before the client can then connect to it.
- Potential buffer overflows.
- Resource leaks.
- A lack of decent error handling.

  - On the server side, you are completely ignoring errors reported by `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, and `send()`, and you are not checking the return value of `accept()` correctly.
  - On the client side, you are completely ignoring errors reported by `socket()` and `recv()`. And, you are not ensuring the `MOTD` buffer is null-terminated before printing it to `std::cout`.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

// The below variables are used to let the client wait for the server
// port to be opened. If you don't want to use these, especially if the
// client and server are ever run on different machines, you can omit
// these and instead just have the client call connect() in a loop
// until successful...
//
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
static std::condition_variable server_cv;
static std::mutex server_mtx;
static bool server_is_listening = false;
//

static const int num_threads = 2;
static const u_short server_port = 1111;

class winsock_error : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    int errCode;
    std::string funcName;
    winsock_error(int errCode, const char *funcName) : std::runtime_error("WinSock error"), errCode(errCode), funcName(funcName) {}
};

void WinSockError(const char *funcName, int errCode = WSAGetLastError())
{
    throw winsock_error(errCode, funcName);
}

class connection_closed : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    connection_closed() : std::runtime_error("Connection closed") {}
};

class socket_ptr
{
public:
    socket_ptr(SOCKET s) : m_sckt(s) {}
    socket_ptr(const socket_ptr &) = delete;
    socket_ptr(socket_ptr &&src) : m_sckt(src.m_sckt) { src.m_sckt = INVALID_SOCKET; }
    ~socket_ptr() { if (m_sckt != INVALID_SOCKET) closesocket(m_sckt); }

    socket_ptr& operator=(const socket_ptr &) = delete;
    socket_ptr& operator=(socket_ptr &&rhs) { m_sckt = rhs.m_sckt; rhs.m_sckt = INVALID_SOCKET; return *this; }

    operator SOCKET() { return m_sckt; }
    bool operator!() const { return (m_sckt == INVALID_SOCKET); }

private:
    SOCKET m_sckt;
}

template <typename T>
T LimitBufferSize(size_t size)
{
    return (T) std::min(size, (size_t) std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
}

void sendRaw(SOCKET sckt, const void *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    const char *ptr = static_cast<const char*>(buffer);
    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        int numToSend = LimitBufferSize<int>(buflen);
        int numSent = ::send(sckt, ptr, numToSend, 0);
        if (numSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            WinSockError("send");
        ptr += numSent;
        buflen -= numSent;
    }
}

void recvRaw(SOCKET sckt, void *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        int numToRecv = LimitBufferSize<int>(buflen);
        int numRecvd = ::recv(sckt, ptr, numToRecv, 0);
        if (numRecvd == SOCKET_ERROR)
            WinSockError("recv");
        if (numRecvd == 0)
            throw connection_closed();
        ptr += numRecvd;
        buflen -= numRecvd;
    }
}

void sendStr(SOCKET sckt, const std::string &str)
{
    uint32_t len = LimitBufferSize<uint32_t>(str.size());
    uint32_t tmp = htonl(len);
    sendRaw(sckt, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    if (len > 0)
        sendRaw(sckt, str.c_str(), len);
}

std::string recvStr(SOCKET sckt)
{
    std::string str;
    uint32_t len;
    recvRaw(sckt, &len, sizeof(len));
    len = ntohl(len);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        str.resize(len);
        recvRaw(sckt, &str[0], len);
    }
    return str;
}

void server_thread()
{
    std::cout << "[Server] Starting ..." << std::endl;

    try
    {
        socket_ptr sListen(::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP));
        if (!sListen)
            WinSockError("socket");

        SOCKADDR_IN addr = {};
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ::inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        addr.sin_port = ::htons(server_port);

        int addrlen = sizeof(addr);

        if (::bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            WinSockError("bind");

        if (::listen(sListen, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            WinSockError("listen");

        // this is optional...
        {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(server_mtx);
        server_is_listening = true;
        }
        server_cv.notify_all();
        //

        std::cout << "[Server] Listening for Client ..." << std::endl;

        socket_ptr newConnection(::accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen));
        if (!newConnection)
            WinSockError("accept");

        std::cout << "[Server] Client Connected!" << std::endl;

        try
        {
            std::string a;
            while (std::cin >> a)
                sendStr(newConnection, a);
        }
        catch (const connection_closed &)
        {
        }
        catch (const winsock_error &e)
        {
            std::cerr << "[Server] Client error: " << e.errCode << " on WinSock function: " << e.funcName << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "[Server] Client Disconnected!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const winsock_error &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "[Server] Error: " << e.errCode << " on WinSock function: " << e.funcName << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "[Server] Unexpected Error! " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "[Server] Stopped!" << std::endl;
}

void client_thread()
{
    std::cout << "[Client] Starting ..." << std::endl;

    try
    {
        // this is optional, could call connect() below in a loop instead...
        std::cout << "[Client] Waiting for Server ..." << std::endl;
        {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(server_mtx);
        if (!server_cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::seconds(5), []{ return server_is_listening; }))
            throw std::runtime_error("Server not listening after 5 seconds!");
        }
        //

        socket_ptr sConnection(::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP));
        if (!sConnection)
            WinSockError("socket");

        SOCKADDR_IN addr = {};
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ::inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        addr.sin_port = ::htons(server_port);

        if (::connect(sConnection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            WinSockError("connect");

        std::cout << "[Client] Connected!" << std::endl;

        try
        {
            std::string MOTD;
            while (true)
            {
                MOTD = recvStr(sConnection);
                std::cout << "[Client] MOTD: " << MOTD << std::endl;
            }
        }
        catch (const connection_closed &)
        {
        }
        catch (const winsock_error &e)
        {
           std::cerr << "[Client] Server error: " << e.errCode << " on WinSock function: " << e.funcName << std::endl;
        } 

        std::cout << "[Client] Disconnected!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const winsock_error &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "[Client] Error: " << e.errCode << " on WinSock function: " << e.funcName << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "[Client] Unexpected Error! " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "[Client] Stopped!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    int ret = ::WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &wsaData);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "WinSock Startup failed with error: " << ret << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "WinSock Startup successful" << std::endl;

    std::thread t[num_threads];

    t[0] = std::thread(server_thread);
    t[1] = std::thread(client_thread);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }

    ::WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are some errors at compile time:

Error:  error: 'src' was not declared in this scope|
At Line:   socket_ptr& operator=(socket_ptr &&rhs) { m_sckt = src.m_sckt; src.m_sckt = INVALID_SOCKET; return *this; }

Error: invalid conversion from 'const u_char* {aka const unsigned char*}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|
At Line:   int numSent = ::send(sckt, ptr, numToSend, 0);

Comment: Error:  no matching function for call to 'min(size_t&, int)'|
At Line:   int numToRecv = (int) std::min(buflen, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
 
Error: invalid conversion from 'const u_char* {aka const unsigned char*}' to 'const char*' 
At Line:   int numSent = ::send(sckt, ptr, numToSend, 0);

Comment: Error: expected ')' before '&' token|
At line:  catch (const socket_closed &)

Comment: Thank you. Still there are some errors when comiling, 

In Code Blocks:
Line 15: 'chrono_literals' is not a namespace-name
Line 111: 'value' was not declared in this scope
Line 177: expected ')' before '&' token
Line 236: 'e' was not declared in this scope


In Visual Studio:  
Error:    error C2039: 'chrono_literals': is not a member of 'std'
Error:    note: see declaration of 'std'
Error:    error C2871: 'chrono_literals': a namespace with this name does not exist

Comment: @Freeman123 I fixed the errors. FYI, `chrono_literals` is in C++14 and later, are you using just C++11 instead? I have replaced `chrono_literals` so it should compile in C++11 now.

Comment: I have an error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::_Bind_helper<false, socket_ptr&, sockaddr*, unsigned int     at line:   if (bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) .  How can I fix this

Comment: After reinstalling Code Blocks I'm getting error:  'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type| and use of deleted function 'socket_ptr::socket_ptr(const socket_ptr&)'|

Comment: @Freeman123 I fixed the mutex and bind errors. But you didn't indicate where the `socket_ptr` copy constructor is being called from. It shouldn't be getting called at all. That is part of why I `delete`d it. Making a copy of a socket requires extra work to duplicate the `SOCKET` handle, and it is not desirable in this code example anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing , there is a small error at line :  template <typename T>T LimitBufferSize(size_t size){
 return (T)std::min(size, (size_t)std::numeric_limits<T>::max);
};    error: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'

Comment: @Freeman123 you are missing parenthesis on `::max`, it should be `::max()`, like I have it in my answer. And you don't need `;` after the closing  `}`